# Glassfish server administration console crash when deploy a proiect in the root

Tags: glassfish

When deploy an application in the root (/) of my domain (when I set "Context Root:" like in [image](http://img4.imageshack.us/img4/1184/immagine2dk.jpg)), Glassfish server administration console crash. After refresh instead the administration console appears the site that I have load in the root. (Why?). So I restart the service and all is ok: the new  application run on root and on port 4848 there is the administration console. Why?, how to fix this?

(Console is on port 4848.
Site domain root is on port 8080 redirect by iptable on 80.)

Comment: were you able to fix this? I'm having similar issue.. in context root I see glassfish home (the page that says glassfish is running ok), and if I refresh the page, I see my webapp

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the context-root to "/" I would recommend to set the default web-module under `"server-config" -> "virtual server" -> "server" -> and select your app in "default web-module"`. Note that your app have to be deployed to select it there.